# Average kinetic energy of a molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

We know average kinetic energy of a molecule in case of gases depends only on temperature. But does same thing applies to liquids and solids as well. I mean does average kinetic energy of a molecule in liquids and solids too depend only on temperature?

Comment: Hi, we expect folks to do at least a little research on their own before posting.  You should look up the definition of "temperature"  and then decide whether there's anything about any standard state of matter that would cause the definition to change.

Comment: The downvote and the "homework" close option are a little harsh, IMO.   This does not sound homework-like to me, as for the "please do research first", yeah, we do ask for some background work.  We want to help with what you don't understand, not with what you can read on your own.